# Imagick WriteBlob Failed 1642

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to get png covers out of pdf books but I'm currently stuck.
The script was working fine. then I changed the virtualhost and reimported all files, adapted path and permissions, but now it's not working.

The error I get is:

`` Uncaught ImagickException: WriteBlob Failed `/var/www/domain/public_html/libreria/covers/architettura dei calcolatori - andrew s-cover.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1642 in /var/www/domain/public_html/list.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/domain/public_html/list.php(61): Imagick->writeimage('/var/www/librer...') #1 /var/www/domain/public_html/libreria/index.php(58): include('/var/www/librer...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/domain/public_html/list.php on line 61 ``

Everything under `/var/www/domain/public_html/` has apache ownership and 775 permissions.

The code snippet where the conversion takes place is the following:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

/*$bookArray[] = $row["bookname"];
print_r($bookArray);*/

$book = $row["bookname"];
$path = $host."/libreria/books/".$row["bookname"];
$truepath = basename($path);
$fileArr = explode('.', $book);
$coverName = strtolower(reset($fileArr))."-cover.png";
$fileExt = strtolower(end($fileArr));

//echo "<a href='$truepath'>".$row["bookname"]."</a><br>";

if ($fileExt == "pdf") {
  $im = new imagick($book.'[0]');
  $im->setImageFormat('png');
  $im->resizeImage(150,200,1,0);
  $im->writeImage('/var/www/domain/public_html/libreria/covers/'.$coverName);
echo "<a href='$truepath'>"."<img src='covers/".$coverName."'>".$row["bookname"]."</a><br>";
} else {
  //  echo "<a href='$truepath'>".$row["bookname"]."</a><br>";
}
```

I checked but I was unable to find out what error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1642 is about.

Can anybody give a sugegstion about this?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this error and solved it by double checking the path I was trying to write to. Make sure the path exists and you have write access.